# angular2 custom template validator has stale values

Tags: validation, angular, typescript

I am stuck for a while now with the following problem. I am implementing an angular 2 custom validator that simply checks if a number is within a range. Used like this, everything works fine:

```
<input type="text" id="doseSimple" class="form-control"
       required 
       name="doseSimple" 
       [(ngModel)]="doseSimple"
       #doseControl ="ngModel"
       validateRange
       from="2"
       to="20"
       >

<div *ngIf="doseControl.errors && (doseControl.dirty || doseControl.touched)">
   <span *ngIf="doseControl.errors.tooSmall">Too small</span>
   <span *ngIf="doseControl.errors.tooBig">Too big</span>
</div>
```

In my case, the validation is a bit more complex. There is a dropdown. The from and to values depend on the selection of the dropdown. There is just an event attached to the dropdown that sets *doseFrom* *doseTo* properties:

```
  <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control"
         required 
         name="doseComplex" 
         [(ngModel)]="doseComplex"
         #doseComplexControl ="ngModel"
         validateRange
         [from]="doseFrom"
         [to]="doseTo"
         >
  <div *ngIf="doseComplexControl.errors && (doseComplexControl.dirty || doseComplexControl.touched)">
     <span *ngIf="doseComplexControl.errors.tooSmall">Too small</span>
     <span *ngIf="doseComplexControl.errors.tooBig">Too big</span>
  </div>
```

The validator validates the value, but with *from* and *to* from the selection before. The values of from and to are like a step behind. How to fix that?

I created a plunker to show the problem:
https://plnkr.co/edit/C0sbL8pRwsZcEZ5r1ODY?p=preview

Comment: it's going just fine

Comment: Unfortunately not :(. When you type a new value in text box, then yes it works fine. But when another range is selected in the dropdown, the validator has the old range. When doseControl.updateValueAndValidity() is called (in component), the validator did not get the new values yet. How can i force the binding to update before i call doseControl.updateValueAndValidity().

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would implement `registerOnValidatorChange` method to do it working:

```
export class RangeValidator implements Validator {
  @Input()
  get from() {
    return this._from;
  }
  set from(value: number) {
    this._from = value;
    if (this._onChange) this._onChange();
  }

  @Input()
  get to() {
    return this._to;
  }
  set to(value: number) {
    this._to = value;
    if (this._onChange) this._onChange();
  }

  validate(c: FormControl): { [key: string]: boolean; } {
    ...
  }

  private _from: number;

  private _to: number;

  private _onChange: () => void;

  registerOnValidatorChange(fn: () => void): void { 
    this._onChange = fn; 
  }
}
```

**[Modified Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/q6bvuhfG6sq9J1TPfuvI?p=preview)**

And you can delete `updateValueAndValidity`

See also angular source code

- https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.0.0-rc.5/packages/forms/src/directives/validators.ts#L67-L90

Comment: Very informative answer - thanks. I have a similar problem with Angular 8 but  couldn't open your demo on plunker so I copied your code into an Angular 8 template [here on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-chwfjy). Maybe someone else will find it useful.